# How to make Multilevel Drop down navigation in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I need same menu like on this site http://www.salesforce.com/aloha.jsp in wordpress theme. Multilevel dropdown mouse hover. is anybody know and trick, techniques or wp-plugin todo samelike this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do it in straight CSS using the [Suckerfish method](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns).

And here's an [alternate version](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) that claims to be more accessible.

**EDIT**: Also, here's a [good article by Jakob Nielsen on dropdown heuristics](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/mega-dropdown-menus.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you can integrate jQuery to your wordpress blog then you can use the superfish jquery plugin as demonstrated [here](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/).  Click examples and then nav-bar style (for some reason I can't link directly).

Comment: Can u give me a tutorial about how to integrate superfish menu into wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

```
Slide down and slide up all tears of wordpress menu items on click function:

<script> 
jQuery('.sub-menu').hide(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  jQuery('li.menu-item-has-children a').on("click", function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('menu-item-has-children')){
       window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        } 
    jQuery(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
  });
}); 
</script>
```